# Maximo animation i dont want my character to move with it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have imported some Maximo animations, but when i use them i see that the character moves with the animation. when i  walk for example i want it to be done via code and not the animation. how can i do this?

my animation rig is set to Humanoid, and also to loop when it ends.

i have tried to check if i can find it in the animation window, and if i can see the changes but no result. i think its the animation itself that changes its position. so please help me find this out or help me find another software where i can create an animation without moving the player.

i am talking about walking/running animations i need a way to not move it via the animation but via my character controller script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you just need to turn off root motion.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-applyRootMotion.html

Just pick your avatar and uncheck "Apply root motion", or you can change it via code if you prefer.

Comment: on a script with a reference to your animator: `animator.applyRootMotion = false;`